# Views field rewrite onClick attribute not rendering

Tags: 7, views

In a D7 instance, in Views under "Rewrite the output of this field" I have this in the textarea:

```
<a href="[field_downloads]" title="[field_downloads_1-description]" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Downloads', '[field_downloads_1-description]'); return false;">[field_downloads_1-description]</a>
```

All data is displaying except for the onClick attribute. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views rewrite uses the [filter_xss_admin](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss_admin/7) function to produce safe html. It's designed as a security measure and is in place even if the user has permissions to add PHP and unfiltered HTML in other contexts.

You can work around by using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) for example. See [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/853880) at drupal.org for discussion and more on workaround approaches.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a few hours digging around, I found the code based solution. You can't add onClick attributes within the Views UI because of xss filtering.

This code can be used in a custom module.

```
// Adding custom link attributes to a views field for ajax calls.
// See around line 1330 in views_handler_field.inc.(drupal 7)

function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_expected_view_name' && isset($view->field['my_field_name'])) {
    $attributes = array('onclick' => "alert('Hello')");
    $view->field['my_field_name']->options['alter']['link_attributes'] = $attributes;
  }
}
```